# How to fill a div with JSON content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, button

I want to be able to fill a div with content from JSON when I click a button. I only want 1 object from the array of objects to fill the div at a time (when different buttons are clicked, different objects from the array populate the div).

I am starting with baseline code and working my way up to this. I have the JSON loaded, but I don't know how to create code that runs through the objects in my JSON array to find the object that I want to populate the div. (I want the div to hold the chapterName content in this example)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("documents/Exercises.json", function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        document.getElementById("thisdiv").innerHTML = feild.Content;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<div id="thisdiv"></div>
```

**JSON**

```js
[
  {
    "ID": "Exercise 1.1",
    "ChapterName": "Chapter 1",
  },
  {
    "ID": "Exercise 1.2",
    "ChapterName": "Chapter 2 ",
  },
  {
    "ID": "Exercise 1.1",
    "ChapterName": "Chapter 3",
  }
]
```

My trouble is the field section and using each, I don't think this is a good way to go about it.

Comment: `document.getElementById("thisdiv").innerHTML = result[the_index_if_the_object].Content`

Comment: For starters, feild.Content should be field.Content

Comment: Do you just want to print one JSON struct into the div?

Comment: yes, I want to just print one in the div, like just have it say "chapter 2"

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to output the JSON as string

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("documents/Exercises.json", function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        document.getElementById("thisdiv").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(field.Content);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<div id="thisdiv"></div>
```

Working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let content = [{
      "ID": "Exercise 1.1",
      "ChapterName": "Chapter 1",
    },
    {
      "ID": "Exercise 1.2",
      "ChapterName": "Chapter 2 ",
    },
    {
      "ID": "Exercise 1.1",
      "ChapterName": "Chapter 3",
    }
  ];
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("thisdiv").innerHTML = "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(content,undefined, 2) +"</pre>";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Click</button>
<div id="thisdiv"></div>
```